# C# Unity My code won't allow for one class to edit the variables in another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a small game where the player flies a rocket to a green platform to progress. If they crash, they start over. The levels simply loop and the gameplay works fine. The issue I'm having is with the timer. I'm trying to make a system that keeps track of how long it takes the player to beat every level, and then save their fastest time under the record variable. I tried adding a hotkey in the Timer script to reset the timer, but if I run the same ResetTimer function from the Rocket script, the currentTime variable will not change. It still prints "Timer reset" but the variable stays the same. Any ideas?

**Rocket.cs**

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Rocket : MonoBehaviour
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();


    [SerializeField] float rotationThrust = 100f;
    [SerializeField] float mainThrust = 50f;
    [SerializeField] float levelLoadDelay = 2f;

    [SerializeField] AudioClip mainEngine;
    [SerializeField] AudioClip success;
    [SerializeField] AudioClip death;

    [SerializeField] ParticleSystem mainEngineParticles;
    [SerializeField] ParticleSystem successParticles;
    [SerializeField] ParticleSystem deathParticles;

    Rigidbody rigidBody;
    AudioSource audioSource;

    enum State { Alive, Dying, Transcending }
    State state = State.Alive;

    bool collisionsEnabled = true;

    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }
        if (state == State.Alive)
        {
            RespondToThrustInput();
            RespondToRotateInput();
        }
        if (Debug.isDebugBuild)
        {
            RespondToDebugKeys();
        }
    }

    private void RespondToDebugKeys()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
        {
            LoadNextLevel();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K))
        {
            LoadFirstLevel();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            collisionsEnabled = !collisionsEnabled;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            timer.ResetRecord();
        }
    }

    private void RespondToThrustInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            ApplyThrust();
        }
        else
        {
            audioSource.Stop();
            mainEngineParticles.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void ApplyThrust()
    {
        rigidBody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * mainThrust);
        if (!audioSource.isPlaying)
        {
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(mainEngine);
        }
        mainEngineParticles.Play();
    }

    private void RespondToRotateInput()
    {
        rigidBody.freezeRotation = true;
        float rotationSpeed = rotationThrust * Time.deltaTime;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationSpeed);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * rotationSpeed);
        }

        rigidBody.freezeRotation = false;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (state != State.Alive || !collisionsEnabled)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (collision.gameObject.tag)
        {
            case "Friendly":
                break;
            case "Finish":
                StartSuccessSequence();
                break;
            default:
                StartDeathSequence();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void StartSuccessSequence()
    {
        state = State.Transcending;
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(success);
        successParticles.Play();
        Invoke("LoadNextLevel", levelLoadDelay);
    }

    private void StartDeathSequence()
    {
        state = State.Dying;
        audioSource.Stop();
        deathParticles.Play();
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(death);
        Invoke("LoadFirstLevel", levelLoadDelay);
    }

    public void LoadFirstLevel()
    {
        timer.ResetTimer();
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }

    private void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        int currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
        if (currentSceneIndex + 1 == SceneManager.sceneCountInBuildSettings)
        {
            timer.Save();
            LoadFirstLevel();
        }
        else
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneIndex + 1);
        }

    }

}
```

**Timer.cs**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{

    float currentTime;
    float record = -1f;
    public Text currentText;
    public Text recordText;


    private void Start()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat");

        PlayerData data = new PlayerData();
        if (RecordTest() == true)
        {
            if (currentTime < record)
            {
                record = currentTime;
                data.recordSave = record;
            }
        }
        else record = currentTime;
        data.recordSave = record;

        bf.Serialize(file, data);
        file.Close();
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat", FileMode.Open);
            PlayerData data = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();

            record = data.recordSave;
        }
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        CheckForResetInput();
        SetCurrentTimeText();
        SetRecordTimeText();
    }

    private void SetRecordTimeText()
    {
        if (record == -1)
        {
            recordText.text = "N/A";
        }
        else
        {
            string minutesRecord = Mathf.Floor(record / 60).ToString("00");
            string secondsRecord = Mathf.Floor(record % 60).ToString("00");

            recordText.text = minutesRecord + ":" + secondsRecord;
        }
    }

    private void CheckForResetInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            ResetTimer();
        }
    }

    private void SetCurrentTimeText()
    {
        currentTime += Time.deltaTime;

        string minutes = Mathf.Floor(currentTime / 60).ToString("00");
        string seconds = (currentTime % 60).ToString("00");

        currentText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }

    public void ResetTimer()
    {
        print("Timer reset");
        currentTime = 0;
    }

    public void ResetRecord()
    {
        record = -1f;
    }

    public bool RecordTest()
    {
        if (record == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }
    public void Collided()
    {
        print("Ouch");
    }
}

[Serializable]
class PlayerData
{
    public float recordSave;
}
```

Comment: Try declaring `currentTime` as `volatile`, ie: `volatile float currentTime;` at the top of the class file.

Comment: Using `new` on a type of `MonoBehaviour` is **forbidden**! The only way for creating instances of components is either `Instantiate` a prefab with that component attached or use `AddComponent`.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 4):

Serializedfields with no other modifier are PRIVATE to the class they are in. Serializedfields are purely for them to show in the unity inspector, they need to be public for you to access them from other classes

So

`[SerializeField] float rotationThrust = 100f;` is private to Rocket

`[SerializeField] public float rotationThrust = 100f;` will be visible to other classes with a reference to a Rocket  instance - Technically you dont need to serialize the field as public will always show, but it makes it look nice in  your code if they all line up :D

Comment: `it makes it look nice in your code if they all line up` lol ^^ yes actually `public` fields (of a serializable type) are serialized anyway by default so it would be redundant to keep the tag actually ;)

Comment: The main issue though is this `new Timer` which is a no-go in Unity ;)

Comment: No, that never helps either

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of Timer for your Rocket component.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

This means that when rocket calls timer.ResetTimer() is resetting the newly instanced Timer class, but NOT the MonoBehaviour attached to your scene object.

Rather than declare a new timer in your rocket class, create a reference to it in the inspector via:

```
[SerializeField] Timer timer;
```

and drag/drop your Timer object to that reference.

---

The above solution is probably the best pattern, **but if you want a quick and easy solution, change your currentTime to static:**

```
private static float currentTime
```

Making this value static means that all Timer instances will share the same value. Since the variable is static, it is not specific to a single class instance. With this solution you are not eliminating the multiple instances of Timer, but you are forcing them to share a currentTime variable. This doesn't fix the design that caused your problem, but it does fix the symptom. This is why I say it is not the best solution.

Comment: In general using `new` for classes of type `MonoBehaviour` is **forbidden**. It makes no sense since they can not exist without being attached to a certain GameObject.